# Magento 2: Safari (only) TypeError for window object

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, browser

Can anyone explain why I'm receiving this error on the Cart page on Safari:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.checkoutConfig.quoteData')`

This happens intermittently and not every time the page loads. Interestingly, it never occurs if the page is refreshed, only if i access the page by hitting return in the browser URL input.

Though it only happens once in a while, it kills the rest of my JS from executing, so I need to find a solution.

Comment: any solutions ? i too face the same issue

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139588)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139588)